# Convert object type into datetime in Time series Forecasting

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, time-series

I am working on Time Series so I want to convert **object type to datetime**. I have a data frame like this:

```
   trxyear  trxmonth
0   2014    JUL-13
1   2014    JUL-13
2   2014    JUL-13
3   2014    JUL-13
4   2014    JUL-13
... ... ...
46394   2023    SEP-22
46395   2023    SEP-22
46396   2023    SEP-22
46397   2023    SEP-22
46398   2023    SEP-22
```

I want to convert `trxmonth` to datetime so I can apply time series. but when I convert using this code

**CODE:**

```
from dateutil import parser
print(parser.parse("JUL-13"))
```

**OUTPUT:**
`2022-07-13 00:00:00`

but it can convert `July 2013` to `13 July 2022`.

**CODE:**

```
print(parser.parse("01-JUL-13") )
```

**OUTPUT:**
`2013-07-01 00:00:00`

when I use this code it can converts correctly but my data is not in this format.
Simply I want to convert `JUL-13` --> `01-07-2013`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `format` parameter:

```
df['trxmonth'] = pd.to_datetime(df['trxmonth'], format='%b-%y')

print (df)
       trxyear   trxmonth
0         2014 2013-07-01
1         2014 2013-07-01
2         2014 2013-07-01
3         2014 2013-07-01
4         2014 2013-07-01
46394     2023 2022-09-01
46395     2023 2022-09-01
46396     2023 2022-09-01
46397     2023 2022-09-01
46398     2023 2022-09-01
```